# add "n" in the y-axis in bracket on a bar graph of proportion when looking at a single categorical variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, categorical-data

I am making a proportional bar graph with error bars. I need to have the number and percentage in the y-axis category name. For eg. Male (n=203/360, 56.38%).

```
variable_count_census %>% 
ggplot(mapping=aes(x = prop, y= y_category)) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity" , colour="black" )+
geom_errorbar( aes(y=category, xmin=conf_low_percent, xmax=conf_high_percent), width=0.4, colour="orange", alpha=0.9, size=1.3)+
 labs (x="Proportion of bites",y="Sex of victim")+ 
ggtitle ("Gender distribution of bite victims")
```

The type of df and desired plot is this picture:

[Desired plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Frezo.png)

Can someone please guide me how to do it?

This is my data (using dput):

```
structure(list(location = c("Overall", "Overall"), variable = c("vic_sex", 
"vic_sex"), category = c("Male", "Female"), sur_count = c(203, 
157), sur_percentage = c(56.38, 43.61), total_sample = c(360, 
360), popn_count = c(277131, 274536), popn_percentage = c(50.23, 
49.76), popn_prop = c(0.5023, 0.4976), total_popn = c(551667, 
551667), estimate = c(`probability of success` = 0.563888888888889, 
`probability of success` = 0.436111111111111), statistic = c(`number of successes` = 203, 
`number of successes` = 157), p.value = c(0.0203402327860262, 
0.0203574137809605), parameter = c(`number of trials` = 360, 
`number of trials` = 360), conf.low = c(0.510925544625987, 0.384207169337693
), conf.high = c(0.615792830662307, 0.489074455374013), method = c("Exact binomial test", 
"Exact binomial test"), alternative = c("two.sided", "two.sided"
), prop = c(`probability of success` = 56.3888888888889, `probability of success` = 43.6111111111111
), low_prop = c(51.0925544625987, 38.4207169337693), upper_prop = c(61.5792830662307, 
48.9074455374013), proportion = c(`probability of success` = 56.3888888888889, 
`probability of success` = 43.6111111111111), conf_low_percent = c(51.0925544625987, 
38.4207169337693), conf_high_percent = c(61.5792830662307, 48.9074455374013
)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- variable_count_census %>% 
    mutate(label_y = paste0(category, "\n(n= ", sur_count, "/", 
                            total_sample, " , ", sur_percentage, ")"), .before=1) %>% 
    mutate(category = factor(category, levels = c("Female", "Male")))

ggplot(df, aes(x = label_y, y = proportion)) +
  geom_col(fill = "gray45", color = "black") +
  geom_errorbar(
      aes(ymin = low_prop, ymax = upper_prop),
      width = 0.4, colour = "orange", alpha = 0.9, size = 1.3,
      position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)
    ) +
    labs(x = "Sex of victim", y = "Proportion") +
    ggtitle("Gender distribution of bite victims")+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]